# Scala sbt-assembly, unable to get resource for org/pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I need to build fat executable jar. Using IntelliJ IDEA, `scala (2.12.4)`, `sbt (1.1.1)` on Windows behind the proxy. Also, using http://babun.github.io/.
Succeeded so far, except building fat jar using `sbt-assembly`.

- created `project/assembly.sbt`

  `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")`
- created `project/plugins.sbt`

  `resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)`

  `resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")`

It looks like it is able to grab `com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6`, but probably fails with it's dependencies,  errors are:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/jars/jarjar.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[warn]  sonatype-releases: unable to get resource for org/pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/jarjar-1.6.5.pom: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.pantsbuild:jarjar:1.6.5
[warn]            +- com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (I:\Scala\SealJils\project\assembly.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:sealjils-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/jars/jarjar.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
[error]         sonatype-releases: unable to get resource for org/pantsbuild#jarjar;1.6.5: res=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/jarjar-1.6.5.pom: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
```

At the same time, I'm able to access following link via my Company browser, hence going via proxy:

`https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/pantsbuild/jarjar/1.6.5/`

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by downgrading `sbt` version to `0.13.17`. Also, it was enough to just have following file included:

`project/assembly.sbt`

```
    addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```